# Tossing the coin $2n$ times, win if tossed heads $>n$ times

Tags: probability-theory

We have a coin with probability of heads $p = 0.48$, we toss it $2n$ times and win, if coin landed heads more than $n$ times. We can choose $n$. What $n$ should we pick?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the max is $n=1,2$ or $3$

Comment: @JorgeFernández Numerically, the answer seems to be 12 rather

Comment: oh, that makes little sense to me

Comment: The only reason I could give for that is the probability for the number of heads to be exactly one half goes down.

Comment: I got n=12 and n=13 are the same and both maxes, numerically.  34.4%

Answer (score 2):

With $n=0$, our winning probability is $0$. With $n=1$ it is $p^2$. With $n=2$, it is $p^4+4p^3(1-p)=p^3(4-3p)$, etc. You can go on computing explicitly, but when can you stop?

Note that the expected value is $E[X]=0.96n$, the variance is $V[X]=0.4992n$, and you need at least $n+1$ heads. Now use Chebyshev's inequality to obtain a bound.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Unless I made y typo somewhere, Chebyshev is awfully weak / kicks in awfully late here

Answer (score 1):

For what $n$ is this a max?  Somebody who is sharper than I am will have to tell you that...
$$\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n}{{2n}\choose{i}}.48^{i}.52^{2n-i}$$

Answer (score 1):

$n$, in fact, seems to be around $11$ or $12$ or $13$. So for the lack of anything else, I decided to use De Moivre - Laplace integral theorem. This gives me that integral: $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0.0566139 \sqrt{n}}^{1.57359 \sqrt{n}}e^{-x^2/2} dx$$
But estimated error for $n$ with values around $12$ is pretty high — about $0.3$ or so. But from what Wolfram|Alpha tells, this function of $n$ seems convex, which means we can just manually check for the answer, inserting integer values in exact formula, which is $$\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} C_{2n}^{i} 0.48^i 0.52^{2n-i}$$ and see, at which points it gives us the biggest answer, which gives us answer of 12 or 13. This is my answer, I'm not sure it's right.

Answer (score 1):

The optimum $n$ is not unique: for $n = 12$ and $n = 13$, a maximum probability is attained:  $$P(n) = \sum_{k=n}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} (0.48)^k (1-0.48)^{2n-k}$$ has value $$\frac{1222235987447480383482148518100992}{3552713678800500929355621337890625}$$ for both these cases, as found by computer search.  It is easy to see that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} P(n) = 0$, so there is at least one maximum value for some finite $n$.

Comment: Which means, that real optimum is somewhere between 12 and 13.

Comment: @Alew How do you define P(n) when 2n is not an integer?

Comment: @Did Isn't it obvious? You toss the coin and try to catch it in the air before it falls.  ^_^

Comment: @heropup Of course. Silly me. :-)